# How to properly implement location changes listener to xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a listener that captures the location every 10 seconds or 100 meters or so. I am using

> xam.plugin.geolocator

to implement the listener. My problem is the location listener is not working(meaning the changes in location were not capturing or saved in the location cache) when my application is minimized or the application is opened but the phone is locked.

Here is my code:

```
async Task StartListening()
    {
        if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
        {
            var defaultgpsaccuracy = Convert.ToDouble(Preferences.Get("gpsaccuracy", String.Empty, "private_prefs"));
            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), defaultgpsaccuracy, false, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.Other,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            });
        }
    }
```

I place this code in the first view/page of my application in my **login.xaml.cs**

Here are my questions:

1. How can I implement the listener properly so that when the application minimized or the phone/device is locked it still captures the changes of location?
2. What is the best GPS settings I need to capture the changes in location faster and accurately? Right now, my current settings are capturing the location every 10 seconds or 100 meters.

Comment: You will need to implement a foregrounded service in native Xamarin.Android code that includes your location code (but with no Xamarin.Forms references as that code can not be dependent upon having an initialized Forms' application) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: @SushiHangover can you show me an example to on how to do it?

Comment: The link in my comment is to Xamarin docs on starting up a foregrounded server on Androdi

Answer (score 1):

First you need to init StartListening then create event handlers for position changes and error handling

`public Position CurrentPosition { get; set; }
 public event EventHandler PositionChanged;`

Don't forget to init it in your constructor :
`CurrentPosition = new Position();`

`await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), 10, true);
CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanging;
CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;`

Functions :

```
    `private void PositionChanging(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPosition = e.Position;
        if (PositionChanged != null)
        {
            PositionChanged(this, null);
        }
    }

    private void PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }`
```

You can now call `PositionChanged` when ever you want the latest position

Don't forget to stop listening :

```
   `public async Task StopListeningAsync()
    {
        if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
            return;

        await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();

        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= PositionChanging;
        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= PositionError;
    }`
```

Comment: What if I put the function in my App.xaml.cs under the OnSleep() will the application still listens?